# Azure CDN url redirect issues

Tags: azure, redirect, cdn

Im currently trying to move my current redirect engine off a nginx proxy on a linux box to Azure. Currently ive been triyng to do it with this example:

dev.oldurl.com --> dev.newurl.com

This is the rule I currently have:

[CDN Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwQzo.png)

When I have gone to the URL, im just getting a certificate error, I should also add that on the Domains section on the CDN I have this error "CNAME/alias record is not currently detected" I can confirm these are present in our on prem DNS server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you do any proxying in your DNS server? I was having the same `CNAME/alias record is not currently detected` problem today and in my Cloudflare dashboard, I accidentally enabled proxies on the CNAME record that I created for Azure Front Door CDN. After I disabled it, the DNS state changed to `Traffic is delivered securely`.

Answer (score 0):

As for the certificate error. You should have certificates corresponding to the URL's/domain names you are using in respective places. So the nginx server object receiving and redirecting *dev.oldurl.com* requests should have a certificate for *dev.oldurl.com* and the server receiving/handling requests for *dev.newurl.com* should have a certificate for *dev.newurl.com*.

For the CNAME record error, the Azure CDN will be looking at the public DNS records published on the internet. So you should check with your internet DNS provider for your domain to update the records.